# if duplicate entry get id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My problem in `mysql`.
My Table name is `categories`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `cid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `parent` (`parent`,`category_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`parent` and `category_name` are unique fields.

If the record not exists I would like to run insert into command.;

```
select last_insert_id() #get last insert id.
```

UPDATE

MY PHP Code is:

```
$sql = "insert into categories (parent,category_name) values ('".$field[parent]."','".$temp->cat_name."')";
        if (@$db->query($sql)){
            $cid = $db->get_var("select last_insert_id()");
        }else{
            $cid = $db->get_var("SELECT cid FROM categories WHERE parent=".$field[parent]." and category_name='".$temp->cat_name."'");
    }
```

How can I get exist id return?

Comment: Please explain your question "How can I get the ID if you have a record?" so, we can help you.

Comment: if you have a record and you want the ID... just SELECT it? please explain what you mean...

Comment: yes, or you want to find out just id if it is already exists?

Comment: Here `parent` and `category_name` is not unique separately. Rather they are jointly unique.

Comment: Sorry for my english. "How can I get exist id return?"

Comment: `SELECT` the ID first using the natural key, and if there's no result then `INSERT` a new record.

Answer (score 1):

> If the record not exists I would like to run insert into command.;

You can use INSERT IGNORE ....

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `categories` ( `category_name`, `parent` ) values ('A', 1); // will insert it
INSERT IGNORE INTO `categories` ( `category_name`, `parent` ) values ('A', 1); // will ignore it
INSERT IGNORE INTO `categories` ( `category_name`, `parent` ) values ('A', 2); // will insert it
INSERT IGNORE INTO `categories` ( `category_name`, `parent` ) values ('B', 2); // will insert it
INSERT IGNORE INTO `categories` ( `category_name`, `parent` ) values ('B', 2); // will ignore it
```

From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> If you use the `IGNORE` keyword, errors that occur while executing the `INSERT` statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without `IGNORE`, a row that duplicates an existing `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY` value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With `IGNORE`, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

Comment: If I using  insert ignore generate new ID. 
I get already exists ID

Answer (score 0):

```
select last_insert_id()
```

return a `ID` after the successful insert. for further processing you can store it in your database after a successful insert.

also you can use `insert ignore into ....` for avoid duplicate insert

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
$sql = "insert into categories (parent, category_name) values ('".$field[parent]."','".$temp->cat_name."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cid=LAST_INSERT_ID(cid)";

$db->query($sql);
$cid = $db->insert_id;
var_dump($cid);
```